# setTitle with IO String results in type error

Tags: haskell, types, yesod

I am trying the set the title of a web page to a string containing the current year, like this:

```
getCurrentYear :: IO String
getCurrentYear = do
    now <- getCurrentTime
    let today = utctDay now
    let (year, _, _) = toGregorian today
    return $ show year

title :: IO Html
title = do
    y <- getCurrentYear
    return $ toHtml $ "Registration " ++ y

getRootR :: Handler RepHtml
getRootR = do
    (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost personForm -- not important for the problem at hand, comes from the example in the yesod book
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle title -- this is where I get the type error
[...]
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error at the `setTitle` line:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Html' with actual type `IO Html'
In the first argument of `setTitle', namely `title'
[...]
```

I just can't get the current year out of the IO monad (or lift the `setTitle` function into it). I've tried various things without success, so this probably boils down to the fact that I still haven't understood Haskell's type system ;-) Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to SO (although you have been a member for some time). I fixed a few things in your question. Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq to understand how the site works.

Comment: Thank you! You've just removed the tags from the title because they're redundant, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay, found it!!! The solution is to use `liftIO`:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

getRootR = do
    [...]
    defaultLayout $ do
        unwrappedTitle <- liftIO title
        setTitle unwrappedTitle
    [...]
```

Comment: Glad you've found the missing link :)

Answer (score 5):

Your `title` is not a `Html` value per-se. It is wrapped in the `IO`. You have to extract it first.

```
getRootR = do
    [...]
    defaultLayout $ do
        unwrappedTitle <- title
        setTitle unwrappedTitle
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot four your answer Mihai. I tried that already but then I get:  
  
    Couldn't match expected type `GWidget sub0 a0 t0'  
                with actual type `IO Html'  
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: unwrappedTitle <- title

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I was fighting with the backticks ;-)

Comment: What is the type of `setTitle`?

Comment: `setTitle :: Html -> GWidget sub master ()`

Comment: and `defaultLayout :: Yesod a => GWidget sub a () -> GHandler sub a RepHtml`

Comment: Seems like you need some `lift` between `IO` and `Handler` :-/ Try changing type of `title` to `Handler Html` or inline it all the way into `getRootR`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, so I just tried various combinations with liftM, which always resulted in an error. The closest thing to success was `return $ liftM setTitle title` which compiled ok, but the `setTitle` action was not actually performed, i.e. the title tags remained empty.

Comment: Hmm. Try asking on #yesod on IRC then. Sorry but I cannot help here, I'm noobish yet when talking about Yesod.